# python distutils post msi installation

Tags: python, windows-installer, distutils

I am creating a msi installer with the distutils `bdist_msi` command. In my setup file, 
i want to run a code after the msi has installed the package, please help..

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.command.bdist_msi import bdist_msi

import os
import shutil

STARTMENU = "C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/ShotExplorer"
STARTUP = "C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup"
LINK = r"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\shotexplorer\ShotExplorer.lnk"


class MyCommand(bdist_msi):
    def run(self):
        bdist_msi.run(self)

        print "Creating Start Menu Entries"
        if not os.path.exists(STARTMENU):
            os.makedirs(STARTMENU)
        shutil.copy(LINK, STARTMENU)
        shutil.copy(LINK, STARTUP)


setup(
    name = "shotexplorer",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "Tool to explore shots on isilon",
    author = "abhishek.garg",
    author_email = "abhishekgarg12@yahoo.com",
    packages = ["shotexplorer", "shotexplorer.pyHook"],
    package_data = {"":["explorer.ico","quicktime.png","ShotExplorer.lnk","pyHook/_cpyHook.pyd"]},
    include_package_data = True,
    cmdclass = {'bdist_msi':MyCommand}
    )
```

Comment: Which sources did you use to create this?

Comment: The class `MyCommand` you declare in your code is only used while _creating_ the installer, not while _running_ it. Look at http://docs.python.org/3/distutils/builtdist.html#the-postinstallation-script on how to specify a post-instllation script.